# Some $_POST arrays are sometimes empty when using PHP mail

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm having some problems in using php mail function to send a html form's data. The mail function is working fine and I have no problem receiving the email when the form is submitted, but sometimes I got empty arrays in my email.

The code looks like:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$email = $_POST['email'];

      //check if value is set:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

      $everyoneToppingList = substr(implode(', ', $_POST['everyone_platter_topping']), 0);
     $everyoneCondimentList = substr(implode(', ', $_POST['everyone_platter_condiment']), 0);

};  //end isset($_POST['submit']

$len = strlen($email);
if ($len > 0) 
{
$email_body = "Full Name: $title $fullname\n".
"Topping? - $everyoneToppingList\n".
    "Condiment? - $everyoneCondimentList\n\n";

 $email_to = "example@gmail.com"; 


   $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

  $URL= "order.php";
  header ("Location: $URL"); 

    // create email headers


$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Cc: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);    
 }  ?>
```

And the html part looks like:

```
<table style="vertical-align:top;" class="form platter bread" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <span class="bold">
            Choose Your Topping: 
        </span> 
        <span id="errorsDiv_everyone_platter_topping[]">
        </span>
        <td height="7" width="87" align="left" valign="middle">
             <input type="checkbox" name="everyone_platter_topping[]" value="Lettuce" id="everyone_lettuce" />
             <label for="everyone_lettuce">\
                 Lettuce
             </label>
         </td>
         <td height="7" width="87" align="left" valign="middle">
               <input type="checkbox" name="everyone_platter_topping[]" value="Tomatoes" id="everyone_tomatoes" />
               <label for="everyone_tomatoes">
                   Tomatoes
               </label>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I receive the email, sometimes it only shows "Topping? - , , , ," .

Really need help on this and any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: is there any pattern to when it is empty?

Comment: What happens if someone has selected no checkboxes for topping? Is there validation to stop that, or is it a valid choice?

Comment: This is not good HTML.  Also, why are you wrapping the imploded input with a substring method?

Comment: @maxhud The hard and tricky part is that there is not a pattern that I find, sometimes it shows up and sometimes don't.

Comment: @andrewsi When there's no checkboxes for topping selected, the $everyoneToppingList part is not displaying at all. So it only shows "Topping? - " with no commas followed. So I believe this part is functinoning.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I don't remember why I put the substr() there but I just removed them and this time it works and there's no ", , , ," showing in the email! But it's hard to know whether it'll happen again.. does anyone know why it happened? Is it really the substr() that's causing it? Thanks!!

Comment: Sorry I don't know why, and no offense intended but this is really awkwardly written, especially your html.  I'm surprised this renders properly.  I hope this is an experimental project.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to write it over here, but comment section is not enough to mention the doubts regarding your question.

- the elements in the form and the elements used in PHP code does not give clear picture of the question.
- Also `$URL= "order.php";
  header ("Location: $URL");` does not make any sense, it will redirect and mail wont be sent anyways

If I make this subtle changes of

1. removing `header` code from the PHP code
2. adding the `email` input box and `submit` submit button in the html form
3. adding form outside the table with method `POST`

I simply got this code working by making above changes without any trouble.

I suggest you edit a question and ask again or do the suggested changes (of course with some tweaking from your side) and you will code be in working state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the confusion about the code as I only copied and pasted a part of my codes on here 'cause it's too long. So for your suggested changes:

1. The header code was actually working and I can receive emails with no problem.
2. Yes I do have the email input box and submit button in my real form

Answer (score -1):

First initialize your variables before using em.

```
$everyoneToppingList = null;
$everyoneCondimentList = null;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $everyoneToppingList = substr(implode(', ', $_POST['everyone_platter_topping']), 0);
  $everyoneCondimentList = substr(implode(', ', $_POST['everyone_platter_condiment']), 0);

}; 

$len = strlen($email);
if ($len > 0) 
{
    if (!is_null($everyoneToppingList) && !is_null($everyoneCondimentList))
    {
        // Send your mail.
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize to `null` as all variable are global to the function it is in (or document if outside of a function). For the `is_null`, you can just use `isset`.

Comment: he is using a variable which is inside an `if ()` block outside. what if the expected value never gets set?

Comment: @ciriusrob: Then the error will be about an undefined variable/index/i forget the specific wording, and with decent error reporting, the problem will be more obvious than if you preset the value to null.  Once you preset it, it's defined -- even though it still doesn't have a *useful* value -- so now error reporting won't spit out a notice about it.